# How can I link custom community visualization to other pages in a report?

Tags: looker-studio

I built a community visualization with various fields. One field that I'm adding is a URL, composed as the documentation suggests, that links to a filter in another page.

While the URL is fine and working, I cannot use it in a normal link or a form because the iframe in which the community visualization is embedded is sandboxed to allow only scripts.

Is there another way to change the top frame navigation, or switch to another page from within the visualization? Maybe through a javascript call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Community Visualizations do not allow links to external resources, so there's no way to make the visualization act as a link to a filter on another page.